How circular convolution achieves the single-tap equalization in OFDM?
I was wondering how circular convolution achieved using cyclic prefix in OFDM helps to achieve single-tap equalization on frequency domain in the receiver, but without cyclic prefix why this property can't be achieved using linear convolution?

The cyclic prefix makes the channel matrix circulant. A circular matrix can be transformed into a diagonal matrix using Eigenvalue decomposition. This decomposition, along with IFFT (FFT) operations at the Transmitter (Receiver) generate single-tap channels, effectively.  A good reference to OFDM is this NPTEL course (https://nptel.ac.in/courses/117104115)

Please check https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/52029/what-is-about-the-circular-convolution-in-ofdm

This question is similar to: What is about the circular convolution in OFDM. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
